# set callback function for glfw using non-static member function

Tags: c++, callback, glfw

I'm using glfw for setting up the OpenGL visualization. I would like to set the callback function as non-static function to access the class variables. However, when I did below I got the error "reference to non-static member function must be called". I know that the callback function must be static in this case, but is there a way to achieve the objective?

```
class Viewer
{
public:
    Viewer()
    {
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);
    }

private:

    void errorCallback(int error, const char* description)
    {
        // print more class variables
        std::cerr << "Error: " << description << std::endl;
    }

};
```

Comment: Nope it's a `C` interface https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__error.html without an additional parameter. So there is no way to pass a pointer to the class you want to handle the error.

Comment: Why so you need to pass a member function here anyway?  Do you have more than one error handler instance?

Comment: @PaulSanders as said, errorCallback shall be able to access class variables. It can't if it is static.

Answer (score 0):

GLFW is a C interface, and does not support C++ objects. For the window, monitor and joystick callback functions, you can store a user pointer for each of these objects, retrieve it in the callback functions, and use that to call a member function (method) of your objects.

This is not possible with the error callback. Instead, you can use a global variable to store a pointer to a local error handler. The global error callback calls this error handler if this variable is not a `nullptr`. You set this pointer before calling a GLFW function, and restore it or nullify it afterwards.

Note that this simple approach only works for single-threaded applications. If you are calling GLFW functions from multiple threads, you need to ensure the thread safety. GLFW 4 will likely improve upon this.

My C++ is very rusty, so don't expect this to work out of the box, but I believe it demonstrates what you can do:

```cpp
typedef void (*glfw_error_handler_function)(void* user_data, int error_code, const char* description);

thread_local static struct glfw_error_handler_t {
    void* user_data;
    glfw_error_handler_function handler;
} glfw_error_handler = { NULL, NULL };

static void global_glfw_error_handler(int error_code, const char* description) {
    if (glfw_error_handler.handler != NULL) {
        glfw_error_handler.handler(glfw_error_handler.user_data, error_code, description);
    }
}

class Window {
private:
    GLFWwindow* window;
    
    void errorCallback(int error, const char* description) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << description << std::endl;
    }
public:
    Window() {
        window = glfwCreateWindow();
        // error handling omitted for simplicity
    }
    
    void requestAttention() {
        glfw_error_handler_t previousState = glfw_error_handler;
        glfw_error_handler.user_data = this;
        glfw_error_handler.handler = Window::errorCallback;
        
        glfwRequestWindowAttention(window);
        
        // Restore previous error handler state
        glfw_error_handler = previousState;
    }
}

static int main() {
    glfwSetErrorCallback(global_glfw_error_handler);

    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Window window();
    window.requestAttention();

    return 0;
}
```

Another possibility may be to throw a C++ error in the global error handler, and catch it at the location that calls the offending GLFW function.